# Reacting to key events

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to do so that if user press "return" key on his keyboard, app has to do something. I try the following:

```
- (void)keyDown: (NSEvent *) event {
        if ([event keyCode] == 36) {  
            [self doSmthFunction];
        }
}
```

but when I press "return" I just hear the beep sound.

---

Full code

KeyEventController.m

```
#import "KeyEventController.h"
#include "myCustomClass.h"

@implementation KeyEventController
- (void)keyDown: (NSEvent *) event {
        if ([event keyCode] == 36) {
                NSLog(@"log");
        }
}
@end
```

KeyEventController.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface KeyEventController : NSResponder 

@end
```

Comment: What class is this code in? This code should work if it's in a subclass of NSResponder.

Comment: It is subclass of NSResponder

Comment: You need to explain a little more about how your app is set up. Did you set an object in IB to your class?  Did you create something entirely in code?  There's nothing wrong with your code, the problem must be in the structure of your app, or some missing connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to override acceptsFirstResponder, and return YES.  Also, you might need to click in your view ( or whatever it is you subclassed) to have it not beep.  I've tested this, and sometimes, it seems necessary to do these things, and sometimes not.